# Are there any sealed classes alternatives in Dart 2.0?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have Android development background and I'm learning Flutter.

In Android it's a common practice to use Kotlin sealed classes to return a state from ViewModel e.g.

```
sealed class MyState {
    data class Success(val data: List<MyObject>) : MyState()
    data class Error(val error: String) : MyState()
}
```

I want to use similar pattern in Flutter and return a State object from the BLOC class. What is the best way to achieve the same in Flutter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Non-Instantiable, Non-Extendable Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344769/creating-a-non-instantiable-non-extendable-class)

Comment: I need to instantiate it to return an error or success result like: if (...) return MyState.Success(someData) else return MyState.Error("Error message")

Comment: This is now available in Dart 3.0! https://stackoverflow.com/a/76257796/1759443

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Such use case would be done using named factory constructors.

It requires a lot more code, but the behavior is the same.

```
class MyState {
  MyState._();

  factory MyState.success(String foo) = MySuccessState;
  factory MyState.error(String foo) = MyErrorState;
}

class MyErrorState extends MyState {
  MyErrorState(this.msg): super._();

  final String msg;
}

class MySuccessState extends MyState {
  MySuccessState(this.value): super._();

  final String value;
}
```

Comment: Very nice! thank you @rémi-rousselet
A variation on this pattern using an abstract class and implementing its interface is also documented here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33079#issuecomment-388912316

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the same thing. Kotlin sealed classes guarantee that there are no other implementations of the given class outside of the file they're defined in. That means you can exhaust `when` statements (`switch` in Dart) by just providing all possible alternatives as cases, not having to think about potential sub-classes elsewhere.

Comment: @sindrenm It is. See https://github.com/rrousselGit/Freezed which pushes the principle showcase here much further and include things like `when`.

Comment: Right! Yeah, I guess it can be done with a code gen library. 

Comment: @RémiRousselet, how we can use MyState object to get details for msg or value?

Answer (score 8):

Soon Dart is going to support sealed classes.

GitHub Code: [source](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/working/sealed-types/feature-specification.md)

```
sealed class Either {}

class Left extends Either {}
class Right extends Either {}
```

You can now test the sealed class

```
test(Either either) {
  switch (either) {
    case Left(): print('Left');
    case Right(): print('Right');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Rémi Rousselet**'s answer is somehow correct but as **sindrenm** mentioned:

> Unfortunately, this isn't the same thing. Kotlin sealed classes guarantee that there are no other implementations of the given class outside of the file they're defined in. That means you can exhaust when statements (switch in Dart) by just providing all possible alternatives as cases, not having to think about potential sub-classes elsewhere

While there is an active discussion about this feature on **dart language**: [Algebraic Data Types](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/349), but there is some libraries that can help you implement this behavior. You can use this libraries:

[Sealed Unions](https://pub.dev/packages/sealed_unions)

[Super Enum](https://pub.dev/packages/super_enum)

[Sealed Class](https://pub.dev/packages/sealed_class)

And if you are using **BLoC** library you can use this lib:

[Sealed Flutter Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/sealed_flutter_bloc)

I hope that **dart language** add this feature ASAP

Answer (score 6):

Dart 3.0 recently introduced them (available on Flutter 3.10.0). The [full docs](https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#sealed) are here.

They're particularly good for relaying state between your layers (data -> presentation and presentation -> view).

The bonus is that each state can have its own (different) properties that are compile-time safe.

Here's the syntax:

```dart
sealed class Response {}

class Success<Type> extends Response {
  final Type data;
  Success(this.data);
}

class Failure extends Response {
  final Error error;
  Failure(this.error);
}

String toString(Response response) => switch (response) {
      Success _ => response.data.toString(),
      Failure _ => response.error.toString(),
    };

String toTypeString(Response response) => switch (response) {
      Success _ => 'Success',
      Failure _ => 'Failure',
    };
```

You can use either `extends` or `implements`.

When you mark a type sealed, the compiler ensures that switches on values of that type [exhaustively cover](https://dart.dev/language/branches#exhaustiveness-checking) every subtype. This enables you to program in an [algebraic datatype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) style with the compile-time safety you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the package for the Sealed Classes/Unions in Flutter

[Freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed)

This Package provided the features to deal with Data Classes, Sealed Class in Dart/Flutter

Here is the link which explains the beast use of freezed package in Flutter

[Use of Freezed Package in Flutter/Dart](https://resocoder.com/2020/02/11/freezed-data-class-union-in-one-dart-package/)

Comment: i recommend freezed.

Comment: Even if dart has sealed classes now, freezed still has some more nice features.